# Maintaining exact formatting in a listing with hyperlink escape sequences

Tags: spacing, listings

I have some code in which I wish to place hyperlinks. I am using the 'listings package.' I would like the code to look identical, with and without the hyperlinks. Failing that I would like to be able to determine the difference in spacing as I want to maintain tabular alignment to about 80 characters.

I am using escape sequences to insert the hyperlinks, but the character spacing changes.

The MWE below does not have a hyperlink but illustrates the character spacing is different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr}
\lstset{
 escapeinside={/*!}{!*/},
 basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
FooBar
/*!{\scriptsize\ttfamily FooBar}!*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

There are often more than one escape sequences on the same line and things can get very out of alignment.[image: Spacing is tighter in the escaped Version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `columns=fullflexible` then the spacing in the listing will be more or less like normal typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr}
\lstset{
 escapeinside={/*!}{!*/},
 basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
 columns=fullflexible
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
FooBar
/*!{\scriptsize\ttfamily FooBar}!*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative is to avoid to do typesetting in the escape, you would then have to calculate the extension of the link for example with the help of zref-savepos.
The following assumes that the url doesn't contain problematic chars and so can be safely used in an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr,xfp}
\lstset{
 escapeinside={/*!}{!*/},
 basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
 }
\usepackage{zref-savepos,zref-user}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\linklabels[3]{\rlap{\href{#1}{\strut\hspace*{\inteval{\zposx{#3}-\zposx{#2}}sp}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
FooBar
/*!\zsavepos{a}\linklabels{https://www.latex-project.org}{a}{b}!*/FooBar/*!\zsavepos{b}!*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be worth adding that I am now happy with my formatting, but I split the listing into two columns and used a preprocessor in MATLAB to calculate appropriate \hspace commands. The code is extensively commented and all the comments are put in the 2nd column. Minipage was then used to stitch the two parts of the listing together.